# Does FxCop compatible in Mac - Jenkins environment?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, jenkins-plugins

I had installed Jenkins in Mac mini and created a job for my xamarin.ios application.

Now, I want to review the code quality throw FxCop plug-in of jenkins from mac.  Is FxCop compatible with mac? If yes, please let me know the process.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I think you should go with Gendarme, if you have mono you will be able to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you had found the answer by yourself during the time I answer the question for future reference (and for myself finding me searching for that topic regularly).

It is currently not possible to use FxCop on an unix-like system and it is very unlikely this will ever happen.